# What is Facebook developer console?

Tags: android, facebook

What is the exact use or purpose of Facebook developer console. I've an Android app and what is the use to link my apps to Facebook developer console with package name and hash keys?

Answer (score 1):

It is useful if you want to integrate facebook into your app by using the Facebook Graph API.  It is required to do have your app on the developer console to do so and to use your app id with certain requests.

For example, I'm working on an app that implements facebook login with firebase.  In order for this to work I have to put my facebook app id from the developer console on the firebase console.